# Custom Class Events in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a standard way in jQuery to publish and subscribe to custom *class* events? There are countless examples of "custom events" which are always related to some HTML *element*. But what if the javascript *class* Person() want's to publish and fire an event iAmSick which is listened for by a class HealthProfessional()? I guess it could be done with callbacks but isn't there something like [asEvented](https://github.com/mkuklis/asEvented)?

Comment: Well, you could use the `window` object to fire all events at it, and bind all event handlers to it... The corresponding `event` object can then contain information about the class that fired the event, etc.

Comment: Yes you could leverage jQuery that way, but it's not clear to me why that'd be any easier than just writing a simple dispatcher independent of jQuery.  I've worked on and with a simple event pub/sub and in JavaScript that's really an extremely simple thing to set up.  Good question though :-)

Comment: Sime and @Pointy, if you could provide examples/links it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jQuery is a cross-browser JavaScript library that provides abstractions for DOM traversal, event handling, animation, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development.

So the short answer is: no. Thre is no "standard way in jQuery to publish and subscribe to custom class events".

However, if you want to create your own solution, but don't want to start from scratch, I'd highly recommend that you read [Darcy Clarke](http://darcyclarke.me/)'s article:

[Library Agnostic Pub/Sub (Publish / Subscribe)](http://darcyclarke.me/development/library-agnostic-pubsub-publish-subscribe/).

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly pointed me to a wealth of information on the topic. I'd always assumed jQuery, like the retired prototype.js, was more than a DOM manipulator but rather a JavaScript library and enhancer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a DOM-oriented library, to the extent that the maintainers generally resist attempts to introduce general-purpose programming tools such as the pub/sub system you describe.